# Which is the correct verb and why?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, subjects

> Jerry is one of those students who (*miss / misses*) the homework
>   assignment as he leaves early.

In the above sentence which is the correct choice of verb and what's the reason for the choice?
If *Jerry* is the subject then it should be '*misses*'.
But I have seen a rule which says that when using pronouns like '*who*' the verb depends on the noun that appears immediately before the verb.

Answer (score 0):

The correct verb is *miss*, and furthermore the phrase at the end of the sentence should be "as *they leave* early."

This is because *who* refers to *students*, not *Jerry*. Jerry is simply a member of this group of students, *who* all *miss* the homework assignment as *they* leave early.

So yes, if the noun after the subject (*who* in this case) refers to a noun other than the subject (that noun is *students* here), the verb form it takes in the relative clause must match it in number. *Students* is plural, *who* refers to it, so the number of the verb must be plural.